# Which way of initiating constant variable is better

Tags: solidity, tokens

If I want to initiate a constant variable in my smart contract which out these two is better and why

1. I set it outside the constructor like `address token = '0xabc'`
   or
2. In a constructor by accepting token address parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initiate a `constant` variable inside a constructor. But you can initiate an `immutable` variable inside a constructor.

You can declare a `constant` variable outside of the contract or inside of it, but in the end, it will be the same since the compiler will replace every instance of the usage of that `constant` variable by its value.

Take a look at the following example contract and at the explaining comments:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

// Legal. You can declare a `constant` outside of a contract. You can declare a `constant` and assign an expression which will result in a constant value
// that can be determined in constant time.
uint256 constant MAX_SUPPLY = 30 * 10 ** 18;

contract Contract {

    // Illegal, this will not compile. When you declare a `constant` you need to initiate it right away.
    uint256 public constant FEE /*= 1*/; // Uncommenting /*= 1*/ will make it  compile

     // Legal. When declaring a `constant` we need to assign a value at declaration time.
    uint256 public constant MIN_VALUE = 5;

    // Legal. You can declare an `immutable` variable and not assig a value to it right away, but you are forced
    // to assign the value in a constructor if you don't assign it at declaration time
    address public immutable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; // Alright

        // Not right. A `constant` variable cannot de assgined anywhere else, only at declaration time.
        // Remove this line to make it compile.
        FEE = 1; 
    }

    function getValue(uint256 v) public {

        // This will be replaced by `if(5 > v)` at compile time
        if(MIN_VALUE > v) {
            //...
        }

        // This will be replaced by `require(msg.sender == theAddressOfTheMsgValueAtDeplyTimeSetInConstructor, "Not owner")`
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not owner");


        // This will be replaced by something like `uint256 value = 1 * (30 * 10 ** 18) * v;` at compile time.
        uint256 value = FEE * MAX_SUPPLY * v;

    }

}
```

**Conclusion**

If you are declaring an `immutable`, you have the option to assign it in the constructor or at declaration time.

If you are declaring a `constant`, you don't have options, you need to initiate it at declaration time.

If you are using regular variables that you know could change after deployment, you can create a `setter` method to it, like `function setValue(uint256 value)...`.

Answer (score 2):

Constant variables cannot be assigned in the constructor, their value are hard-coded into the byte code **at compilation time**. So, only 1) is possible with `constant` variables.

`immutable` variables on the other hand can be assigned to in the constructor, and just like `constant` variable, their value will be hard-coded into the byte code, but this will be done **at deployment time**.

From there, the answer is relatively simple :

If you know the value of the variable at compilation time use `constant`, otherwise, and if you want to allow some level of customization to that variable, use `immutable` with a constructor parameter.

After deployment (*i.e.,* after the constructor is executed), there is no difference between a `constant` and `immutable` variable, both are hard-coded and cannot be modified.